# ¿Cómo formar un XML con un namespace y atributos en C#?

Tags: c#, xml

requiero armar un xml como el siguiente:

```
<PoliticaControl>
<Dueno>
    <ID>79a59df900b949e55d96</ID>
    <Nombre>Bart</Nombre>
</Dueno>
<ListaAcceso>
    <Grant>
        <Grantee xmlns:xsi="http://www.mysite.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CanonicalUser">
            <ID>79a59df900b949e55d96</ID>
            <Nombre>Bart</Nombre>
        </Grantee>
        <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
    </Grant>
</ListaAcceso>
</PoliticaControl>
```

Esto lo estoy armando en C#, ya tengo toda la estructura, solo que no tengo idea de como añadir en el xmlns:xsi y el xsi:type.

Esto lo estoy haciendo con la clase `XDocument` de C#.

Cualquier pista que me puedan dar se las agradeceré.

**Código:**

```
XDocument xml = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
XElement politicaControl = new XElement("PoliticaControl");
XElement dueno = new XElement("Dueno");
XElement id = new XElement("ID");
XElement nombre = new XElement("Nombre");
XElement listaAcceso = new XElement("ListaAcceso");

XElement grant = new XElement("Grant");
XElement grantee = new XElement("Grantee");
XElement idGrantee = new XElement("ID");
XElement nombreGrantee = new XElement("Nombre");
XElement permission = new XElement("Permission");

xml.Add(politicaControl);
politicaControl.Add(dueno);
dueno.Add(id);
dueno.Add(nombre);
politicaControl.Add(listaAcceso);

listaAcceso.Add(grant);
grant.Add(grantee);
grantee.Add(idGrantee);
grantee.Add(nombreGrante);
grant.Add(permission);

idGrantee.Add("79a59df900b949e55d96");
nombreGrantee.Add("Bart");
permission.Add("FULL_CONTROL");

id.Add("79a59df900b949e55d96");
nombre.Add("Bart");
```

Comment: coloca el codigo de XDocument en c#

Comment: Ya lo corregí, y añadí el código para generar el XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el segundo párrafo de tu código, cuando generas `Grantee` le debes pasar los atributos.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.mysite.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XAttribute xmlnsXsi = new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", ns);
XAttribute xsiType = new XAttribute(ns + "type", "CanonicalUser");
XElement grantee = new XElement("Grantee", xmlnsXsi, xsiType);
```

Esto va generando:

```
<Grantee xmlns:xsi="http://www.mysite.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:type="CanonicalUser">
</Grantee>
```

y ahí adentro se agregan otros elementos.

Comment: Ya lo añadí a mi código y funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias.